# Pattern for 2 digit int with 2 digit decimal in angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

For example, I have to give % field validation that should accept

00.00   to 100.00

Need patterns for the above range. in angular js

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself or do you just expect us to give you a solution? Tell us what you have tried and will tell you what your problem is...

Comment: <input type="number" class="form-control" name="myDecimal" placeholder="Decimal"  ng-model="myDecimal" ng-pattern="(/^[0-9]{1,2})+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" required />   I tried this but its not working

Comment: @VladimirZdenek lol behaving like a typical manager.    Only one line ans it has if u know the solution...

Comment: We are here to help, because we enjoy helping people. But first, we want to see you have tried to come up with a solution yourself. It is also customary to show your appreciation by upvoting and/or accepting the answer which has helped you, be it whichever one...

Comment: Hello @yaswantsingh could you check if [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44669983/4927984) solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

For a number input, you can simply use `min` and `max`:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="myNumber" min="0" max="100" />
```

For a text input, you can use [`ng-pattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) with a regex to validate your field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myNumber" ng-pattern="/^(100|[0-9]{0,2})$/" />
```

*Note that this regex only works for integers. If you want to accept 2 digits numbers, something like `^(100(?:.00)?|[0-9]{0,2}(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?)$` may work.*

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `ng-pattern="^(100|\d{1,2})\.\d{2}$"`.